# Multiple usable computers with only one CPU

Tags: multiple-computers

A long long time ago, I saw there was a software for ubuntu that would let users attach two keyboards, two mice, two screens and then associate the hardware with the software. Then it would let people use the same computer at the same time for different work.

Simple: Two controllers, two screens, different work.

Now, I want to know what such type of software are called (so i can search for them) and i want to know, that if such a software is available for Windows and what's it called.
And if anyone can tell me the name of the software on Ubuntu, that would be great too... :D

Comment: FYI It's now allowed per the EULA for Windows

Comment: @Raystafarian unless it is windows server with Terminal Services licences :)

Comment: or you have two windows licences....

Comment: @IainSimpson I don't think that's correct as a non server Windows installation can only accept a single licence key. Only Terminal Services allows for multi-seat licences.

Comment: @Raystafarian You can't do it in Windows with software, but you can get VDI hardware adapters that (legally) allow this.

Comment: so anyways, let the windows part be, i want to know that can i just run a "MultiSeat" computer with Linux with no additional hardware like the ones the company sells. I am ok with buying a video card, because its cheaper than the proprietary hardware the companies sell.

Answer (score 2):

These softawares are called "**MulltiSeat**" (check on Wikipedia)

Sure it's possible. Get a look at UsefulMultiseat Linux for example.

http://www2.userful.com/products/userful-multiseat-linux

and this

http://www2.userful.com/products/downloads/free-2-user

Comment: and thanks for the answer... i got to know about the system, but do i have to buy a device to connect the extra devices? or can i use the existing ports on my computer to connect it? for the monitor, it might be cheaper to buy a video card which will give me extra ports... what do u think?